# Chrome suggesting password on select box

Tags: google-chrome, password-manager, password-autofill

In my case chrome is suggesting password in select type input.

> This input is on a page where no username or password field is being
> used.

Not a single input is with with name username or password. I have tried **autocomplete="off"** and **autocomplete="disabled"** but no effect. Read many issues of somewhat similar cases but was not able to find any solution of this.

Code is built in vuejs and i am not using input inside form tags

[image]

Very much appreciate any kind of help. Thank you in advance.